# How to treat aar file as a Module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I have a aar file only. Its for a library that i'm interested in changing.  Remember, i have the aar file only. What i would like to do is edit the library with a few tweaks and then
create another aar file (for my own personal use of course).  How can i tell android studio to import this AAR file as a module which i can edit code in ?

I tried going to file-->new-->import new module but it wont let me import a AAR file as a module.

I do not have access to the original Github library only the AAR.

Comment: There is no code for you to edit in an AAR.

Comment: so how do i add to a AAR file, is there anyway ? I opened the AAR file in a text editor and its all binary. but android studio "explodes" aars so i was thinking i  can open them to edit.

Comment: "so how do i add to a AAR file, is there anyway ?" -- if it is open source, work with the source code, not the AAR. If it not open source, license the source code from the AAR authors. If you cannot license the source code, then do not change the library.

Answer (score 1):

Click File->New->New Module and select import /jar/.aar package. It'll wrap the aar in a module and you're good to go.

Comment: I tried this but i cant edit the aar file. its just wraps it in a module in the project structure but i cant view any packages.